# Remove specific tag from xml file in bash

Tags: xml, shell, unix, xml-parsing

I need to remove strings like this:

```
<test-test1 type:name="text.here"/>
```

from an `.xml` file.

I tried, e.g.:

```
variable="<test-test1 type:name=\"text.here\"/>"
sed -i 's|${variable}||g' file.xml
```

but it does not work.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the entire xml file? Do you need to remove everything between `<` and `/>`, that is the whole line?

Comment: I edited the question, I need to replace the entire tag, then I will apply the rule for similar tags in the script.

Comment: What do you mean by "like this"? How alike does the string have to be? Can it be any valid equivalent XML, e.g. written using single quotes around the attribute, using multiple spaces or tabs or newlines in permitted places, using a different prefix bound to the same namespace, using an explicit end tag rather than an empty-element tag? Do you really want to write code that will only work if the XML takes precisely this lexical form? If so, is that wise?

Comment: Variables are not expanded in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Python script to do this for you.
Copy the contents to `filename.py`, apply `sudo chmod +x filename.py` and execute the script. I assumed you used `file1.xml` as your XML file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

your_content: "the words to replace the string"

# here we read the file in Python
fh = open("file1.xml", "r")
content = fh.read()

# Here we match the string, it matches content between  =name=" and \
m = re.sub(r'(?<=name=\")(.*)(?=\")', your_content, content)

print(m)

# now you probably want to write to the file
x = open("file1.xml", "w")
x.write(m)
```

Note, Python 3 works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [double-quotes for variables, not single-quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423446/165517):

```
variable="<test-test1 type:name=\"text.here\"/>"
sed -i 's|'"${variable}"'||g' file.xml
```